# Why does compiler need the assembly file name when compiling the friend assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, .net-assembly, friend

Why does compiler need the assembly file name when compiling the friend assembly?

I am reading the **CLR via C#** book and I come across the following excerpt:

> Note that the C# compiler requires you to use the
>   /out: compiler switch when compiling the friend assembly (the assembly that does not
>   contain the InternalsVisibleTo attribute). The switch is required because the compiler needs to
>   know the name of the assembly being compiled in order to determine if the resulting assembly should
>   be considered a friend assembly. You would think that the C# compiler could determine this on its own
>   since it normally determines the output file name on its own; however, the compiler doesn’t decide on
>   an output file name until it is finished compiling the code. So requiring the /out: compiler
>   switch improves the performance of compiling significantly.
>
> Also, if you are compiling a module (as opposed to an assembly) using C#’s /t:module switch, and
>   this module is going to become part of a friend assembly, you need to compile the module by using
>   the C# compiler’s /moduleassemblyname: switch as well. This tells the compiler what
>   assembly the module will be a part of so the compiler can allow code in the module to access the other
>   assembly’s internal types.

The excerpt above means that the file in which an assembly is put and the assembly have the same name. But that is not the case, because a strongly named assembly name consists of assembly's name, culture, public key, and version number.

Otherwise, I come to a conclusion that it is impossible to give a definition to the assembly name, because the definition of the name assumes that we already know what the name is. Because **name** = **name** + culture + public key + version number.

So, could someone explain in a foolproof manner why does the file name matters for a friend assembly compilation? And what is the relation between the file and assembly names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does compiler need the assembly file name when compiling the friend assembly?

It's stated in the quotation you supplied:

> You would think that the C# compiler could determine this on its own since it normally determines the output file name on its own; however, **the compiler doesn’t decide** on an **output file name** until it is **finished compiling** the **code**. **So requiring the /out:** compiler switch **improves** the **performance of compiling significantly.**

OP:

> The excerpt above means that the file in which an assembly is put and the assembly have the same name. But that is not the case, because a strongly named assembly name consists of assembly's name, culture, public key, and version number.

It doesn't say that at all and that is **not** the definition of a strongly named (SN) assembly.

MSDN:

> *A strong name consists of the assembly's identity — its **simple text name**, version number, and culture information (if provided) — plus a public key and a digital signature.* [More...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/wd40t7ad(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Sure the simple text name may be derived from the assembly/filename at the time it was signed but that is incidental.

OP:

> Otherwise, I come to a conclusion that it is impossible to give a definition to the assembly name, because the definition of the name assumes that we already know what the name is. Because name = name + culture + public key + version number.

Strong-naming (I assume we are still on that point) an assembly occurs **after** the assembly has been generated.  You cannot sign that that does not exist.  If it exists, it has a simple text name.

Also, why are we now talking about .NET strong naming (SN) of assemblies?

Comment: What does the OP mean and what does the SN mean?

Comment: @qqqqqqq Thank-you good sir. OP = _Original Poster_;  SN = _strong naming_

Comment: Got it. Thank you.